# L-sentence for finite degree of algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L=\{0,1,+,-, \cdot \}$ be the language.

This is follow up question on: [Axiomatize purely transcendental field extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696303/axiomatize-purely-transcendental-field-extension).

I'm trying to write an L-sentence that says" the algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is at least of degree $n$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Some thoughts:

- We need to have some distinct $\phi_i$ finite extensions.
- We need to include some properties of finite extension... but I'm not sure what they are.

Thanks in advance!